# level shifting high speed signals

Tags: level-shifting, interface, digital-communications

I have a host of differential signals from a board thats 3.3V. Now, I need to interface it to a board that can accept 2.5V. Now, is it possible to use a standard level shifter like [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74avc32t245.pdf) ?

Is there any effect on the impedance and will there be any impedance mismatch ? If so, how can I add any passives to compensate for it in case of any impedance mismatch issues ?

Finally, there are some clock signals that need the same level shifting. Can such standard level shifters be used as long as the slew rates and the frequency is not compromised ?

Now, my clock is going from one board to another board. And I foresee a degradation of the performance. How can I rectify that ?

Comment: Define "high speed". 10MHz? 100MHz? 1GHz? 10GHz?

Comment: For impedance, consider the level shifter input the end of the line for the 3.3V signal (match about input impedance if needed). Then consider it the start of the line for the 2.5V signal.

Comment: Could you kindly clarify the 2nd comment please ?

Comment: First you need to answer the first comment because the answer will determine how important the second comment is.

Comment: 1GHz please. Thats is the max frequency.

Comment: Then, no, you can't use a standard level shifter like the one you linked to (that only goes up to 200Mbps). It also only supports single-ended inputs, not differential. And yes, impedance becomes a **major** consideration. What I/O standard does your signal use? LVDS? PECL? CML?

Comment: Its CMOS only. Now 200Mbps means a max of approx 200MHz.

Comment: 200Mbps means a max of around 100MHz. CMOS is not a differential standard. Do you have datasheets for the two things you are trying to connect?

Comment: How is it 100Mhz. Consider 200Mbps. It sends a single bit per sample. A sample consists of an on and off time. So 1 bit per sample makes it 200MHz.

Comment: Think of a 50% duty clock signal - if it is high for 5ns, then low for 5ns, that is a period of 100MHz. But to send that through a level shifter it would have to support 200Mbps because it has to send one bit for the first half of the clock and a second bit for the second half of the clock.

Comment: But is that how bits are sent ? 1 bit during Ton and 1 bit during Toff ? I thought that usually 1 bit is transmitted at 1 sample (Ton + Toff).

Comment: A data bit is. But you want to also send a clock signal through, so you have to consider the half period. To think of it another way, if you send a bit stream of 10101010 at 200Mbps, the signal you are sending is effectively a 100MHz square wave.

Comment: I don't mean to sound condescending when I say this, but based how you are presenting the problem, I think you are in way over your head. 1GHz signals are tricky to work with, you need to first learn about impedance control, transmission line effects, and high-speed PCB design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a host of differential signals from a board thats 3.3V. Now, I need to interface it to a board that can accept 2.5V. Now, is it possible to use a standard level shifter like this ?

As comments point out, the part you found is only capable of level-shifting single-ended signals at up to 200 Mbps. You said your maximum rate is 1 GHz.

You can level shift a clock signal by simply ac-coupling and re-biasing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL4NUT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the given resistor values, the bias at the Rx inputs is at Vcc/2. If you need a different common mode voltage, you need to find other resistor values that give that value as voltage divider, and also form a 50-ohm termination (assuming matching a 50-ohm transmission line)

For data signals, you can use the same scheme if the data is balanced (contains equal numbers of 0's and 1's over a span of a few dozen bits). If the data is not balanced, you may have to find an appropriate level shifter for your data rate and source/receiver voltage levels.

> Now, my clock is going from one board to another board. And I foresee a degradation of the performance. How can I rectify that ?

Be sure to use impedance-matched transmission lines to connect between the boards. Be sure to use an appropriate technology for the distance you need to cover.

Comment: Thank you so much. But the clock scheme you have shown is differential. My clock is single ended. Now, regarding the appropriate technology. What do you mean by that ?

Comment: AC-coupling will also work on single-ended clocks. But why use single-ended clock with differential data? Your clock is likely your biggest EMI emitter.

Comment: "appropriate technology" means the right way to do it depends on a bunch of stuff you didn't reveal in the question.